# calculating average hours required per week

Tags: time-series, mean, descriptive-statistics

This may be an embarrassingly simple question - sorry. Let us say I collect hours spent per week to produce widgets. The following table shows a simplified example for 2 widgets:

[image]

Would one calculate the average (e.g. mean) hours required per week like this:

```
mean_hours_week_1 = (10 + 12) / 2 = 11
mean_hours_week_2 = (10 + 11) / 2 = 10.5
mean_hours_week_3 = (3 + 0) / 2 = 1.5
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think $total\_hours/3\_weeks = (10+10+3+11+12)/3$ :)

Comment: @quester - thanks - sorry I do not follow. I require the average per week - so 3 values in this example.

Comment: It might help if you said why you need these estimates.

Comment: @BruceET thanks fro your comment. Sorry for a cluster of widgets, I would like to estimate how many hours are required per week and over how many weeks. The curve would look like a negative exponential I suppose. Guess I could also transpose data and fit a log log model or some other non linear regression model ...

Comment: So you're trying to estimate the exponential rate? Do you expect the three weeks to have significantly different rates? Otherwise, maybe @quester has a point.

Comment: @BruceET I think that OP is calculating **mean per week per widget** but he requires **mean per week**

Comment: @quester - I am sorry. I do not follow. When I calculate (10 + 12) / 2 = 11, I calculate the average hours required for a widget in week 1 - don't I?

Comment: @BruceET - not I expect the curves to be homogenous. The above is just a made up example where I also have a measurement in week 3 for widget with id 1

Comment: I read comment about exponential rate right now - if you want to estimate work time I would say... don't, because if someone will come up with proper model to estimate work time I will vote for him to get Nobel Prize in Economy, are you able to estimate work time of your homework or chores with this kind of approach? time should drop near 0 at some point? are you sure that this widget will not require support time that will consume more time? when project(observed process) is too small and you have too few data points it's better to not over intellectualize life

Comment: @quester I have thousands of the above data points. Obviously I only used 2 to communicate the problem.